# Hibernate Projection returing result as Object

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql

I want to write following sql using projection in hibernate

```
SELECT id, name, MAX(ver)
  FROM bizterm
 WHERE name ILIKE '%AB%'
 GROUP BY name, id  order by name asc
```

I have written following code

```
Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(BizTerm.class);
            criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("name", searchString,MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
            criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("name"));
            ProjectionList projList=Projections.projectionList();
            projList.add(Projections.max("ver"));
            projList.add(Projections.groupProperty("id"));
            projList.add(Projections.groupProperty("name"));
            criteria.setProjection(projList);
```

In the table id,ver are the PKEY.
This query is running fine but in result I am getting value of only 3 column that is ver,id,name that too as Object,There are other column like status,level in the BizTerm table those value are not getting returned in the result set. How can I get those using projection? I tried `projList.add(Projections.property("status"));` but its not working.
I want this query to be executed

```
SELECT id, name,status,level MAX(ver)
  FROM bizterm
 WHERE name ILIKE '%AB%'
 GROUP BY name, id  order by name asc using projection in hibernate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did like this..now its working no error

```
Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(BizTerm.class);
            criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("bizTermName", searchString,MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
            criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("bizTermName"));
            ProjectionList projList=Projections.projectionList();
            projList.add(Projections.max("bizTermversion"));
            projList.add(Projections.groupProperty("bizTermId"));
            projList.add(Projections.groupProperty("bizTermName"));
            projList.add(Projections.max("status"));
            projList.add(Projections.max("levels"));
            projList.add(Projections.max("createDate"));
            projList.add(Projections.max("modifyDate"));
```

Note: I dont need maximum of status,levels,createDate,modifyDate but if I am not writing them inside max function then getting following error

```
[Error Code: 0, SQL State: 42803]  : column "levels" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

with max function everything seems to be fine